# How can I prevent my VB application to crash

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I hope that you can help me with my problem.

I get this error:

> System.Net.WebException:
>   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

when I click on `button_2`. I want to prevent the application from crashing using, show a MessageBox error or something similar.
Can anyone help?

```
Private Sub Guna2Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guna2Button1.Click
    Dim api As String
    api = Guna2TextBox1.Text
    Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("link")
    Dim wc As New WebClient
    Dim data As String
    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
    Try
        response = request.GetResponse()
    Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
        MsgBox("Bad API")
    End Try
    MsgBox("Good API")

        data = wc.DownloadString("link")
        Dim IPV4Regex = New Regex("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$")
        Dim ipstr As String = ("")
        Dim total As String = ("")
        Dim myJObject = JObject.Parse(data)

        For Each match In myJObject("matches")
            Dim ip = match("http")("host")
            If IPV4Regex.Match(ip).Success Then
                ipstr = ip
                total = total + ipstr & vbCrLf
                Guna2TextBox2.Text = total
                Label4.Visible = True
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Write code that correctly generates requests and/or handles exceptions. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement on catching exceptions - there are also many great VB.Net / Exception Handling tutorials online. Search for "VB.net handle exception".

Comment: can you put an exemple please I din't understand

Comment: Put the _text_ of the code in the _question_ (not an image, and especially not an image on a spammy image host). Add additional details to the question to explain the code, as required to improve clarity.

Comment: Try to paste the code in your question

Comment: Anyway, HttpWebRequest will _throw an exception_ on 4xx or 5xx return code. Use `Try..Catch` to deal with these cases. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse?view=netframework-4.8 : "..If a WebException is thrown, use the Response and Status properties of the exception to determine the response from the server.."

Comment: Since a 401 is being returned (as per the thrown exception message), it may indicate that the correct authentication information has not been provided when making the request.

Comment: Don't mix WebRequest and WebClient. Pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse

            Try
                response = request.GetResponse()
            'Put other lines here...
            Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
                msgbox("Something bad happened")
            End Try
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this code but it's the same problem it show's the error msgbox but application still crash

Comment: Ok it still crashes after the messagebox because the variable `response` is being used in the next if statement. I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Why your code dose not stop if api is wrong !!
your code must handle any error before going to next step
at least use Exit Sub

```
Try
    response = request.GetResponse()
Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
    MsgBox("Bad API")

    Exit Sub

End Try
MsgBox("Good API")
```